# Why am I seeing hidden files such as .DS_Store using fts(3) for traverse?

Tags: c

When I go through subdirectories I print hidden files such as .DS_Store along with usual files. I cannot understand why. 
As far as I understand FTS_F flag is for usual files, not hidden files.

Also from documentation:
*By default, unless they are specified as path arguments
to fts_open(), any files named "."  or ".."  encountered
in the file hierarchy are ignored.*

Here is my code:

```
int traverse(char *dirName)
{
    FTS *ftsp;
    FTSENT *p, *chp;
    int fts_options = FTS_COMFOLLOW | FTS_LOGICAL | FTS_NOCHDIR;

    if ((ftsp = fts_open(&dirName, fts_options, NULL)) == NULL) {
        printf("Open failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    /* get all children directories */
    chp = fts_children(ftsp, 0);
    if (chp == NULL) {
        return 0;               /* no files to traverse */
    }

    while ((p = fts_read(ftsp)) != NULL) {
        switch (p->fts_info) {
            case FTS_D:
                printf("d %s\n", p->fts_path);
                break;
            case FTS_F:
                //if(!isHidden(p->fts_path))
                    printf("f %s\n", p->fts_path);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    fts_close(ftsp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "As far as I understand FTS_F flag is for usual files, not hidden files" -- Think about your "understanding" (which is not based on any evidence or sound reasoning). If FTS_F didn't yield  files that start with ".", how would you get them? Now, since it *does* yield them and you don't want them, what is stopping you from ignoring them? "Also from documentation ..." -- How is that relevant? ".DS_Store" is neither "." nor "..", is it?

Comment: `//if(!isHidden(p->fts_path))` -- Why put that only under FTS_F? Do you really want to see hidden directories but not hidden files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as hidden file. Hiding/not-displaying files whose names begin with a dot is purely a convention. If you want to skip processing them, you can do so yourself.

I suspect the source of your confusion is the text you quoted:

> By default, unless they are specified as path arguments to fts_open(), any files named "." or ".." encountered in the file hierarchy are ignored.

This text is referring to files (actually directories) with the names `.` (self) and `..` (parent), not files whose names begin with dots.

Also note that the `fts.h` functions are non-standard, and the versions provided on GNU/Linux (glibc-based) systems are not safe to use because they're not compatible with 64-bit file sizes and inode numbers. If you want to use fts you should get a portable version from one of the BSDs or gnulib to include in your program's source tree rather than using the system one.